# Font Awesome - Not all vector images work

Tags: fonts, github

I'm using the icons from Font Awesome in a print publication and it looks like they've added more recently.  Unfortunately, the new ones don't show up when I copy and paste from the cheat sheet (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) to Photoshop.  I re-installed the font, but that still leaves me with an empty box instead of an icon.

Has anyone had a similar issue and know how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

For what it's worth, here what I did to create png and jpg images from font awesome. Hope it helps you somehow.
http://moodurian.blogspot.com/2013/10/font-awesome-icons-as-png-and-jpg-image.html
Frankie Kam

Comment: Please, post at least summary of your links. That link will be broken sooner or later, and after that this answer is pretty much useless.